# Xen: How to avoid partitioning of image file?

Tags: opensuse, xen, images

I am setting up a openSuSE DomU using image files. But I would like to handle each image file as a *partition* inside the DomU, not a complete *disk* (i.e., I would like to access the image files as hda1, hda2, hda3 instead of hda, hdb, hdc).

Is there any way to achieve this? I know how to handle this in Gentoo, but that's a tinkerer's distro anyway and makes such things easy...

Comment: I would have deleted the question for being stupid, but seeing there's been an upvote on it, I answered myself and unveiled the full amount of my incompetence. :-D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gosh, I must have been blind.

Instead of:

```
disk=[  'file:/var/lib/xen/images/suse/disk0-root,hda,w',
        'file:/var/lib/xen/images/suse/disk1-swap,hdb,w',
        'file:/var/lib/xen/images/suse/openSUSE-11.3-DVD-x86_64.iso,hdc,r' ]
```

simply use:

```
disk=[  'file:/var/lib/xen/images/suse/disk0-root,hda1,w',
        'file:/var/lib/xen/images/suse/disk1-swap,hda2,w',
        'file:/var/lib/xen/images/suse/openSUSE-11.3-DVD-x86_64.iso,hdb,r' ]
```

...which is just the same as I've used for the Gentoo setup. Serves you right when you're copy&pasting tutorials without actually having a close look at them.